# While building a DockerFile Getting This Error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I can't build .net core project from server's terminal.

It gives this error :

> CSC: error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method
> suitable for an entry point [/app/CoreWebApiTest.csproj]  The command
> 'bin/sh -c dotnet publish CoreWebApiTest.csproj -c Release -o out'
> returned a non-zero code:1

This is my dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env 
WORKDIR /app COPY *csproj ./ 
RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet publish CoreWebApiTest.csproj -c Release -o out 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=build-env /app/out . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreWebApiTest.dll"]
```

This is the build command:

```
docker build -t example-image .
```

Comment: I RUN THIS COMMAND ON TERMINAL : docker build -t example-image .

Comment: This is my dockerfile : 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY *csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore


RUN dotnet publish CoreWebApiTest.csproj -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreWebApiTest.dll"]

Comment: Please include these details in the question itself; make sure to use appropriate code formatting.

Comment: @YarenDerici please update the question with your comments